# Can i get help in MongoDB aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am learning aggregation in MongoDB. I have made a database consisting of (emp_id,emp_name,Dept,Salary).

my queries are:

1. Display names & salary of employees working in “Testing” Dept.
2. Display minimum salary from each Dept.

these might sound silly but i need help pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find Testing Dept salaries:

   ```
    db.the_collection.find({Dept:"Testing"},{emp_name:1 , Salary:1 ,_id:0})
   ```

   aggregation way:

   ```
    db.the_collection.aggregate([ {$match:{Dept:"Testing"}} ,{$project:{emp_name:1,Salary:1,_id:0}}    ])
   ```
2. Display min salary by Dept:

   ```
   db.the.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$Dept" , minSalary:{$min:"$Salary"}}    }])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

so considering the following documents have been created...

```
db.test.insert({emp_id: "001", emp_name: "John Doe", dept: "Sales", salary: 59500})
db.test.insert({emp_id: "002", emp_name: "Brian Regan", dept: "Sales", salary: 45000})
db.test.insert({emp_id: "003", emp_name: "Josh Montenegro", dept: "Sales", salary: 45000})
db.test.insert({emp_id: "004", emp_name: "Sarika Rashindra", dept: "Sales", salary: 77200})

db.test.insert({emp_id: "005", emp_name: "Tim Jones", dept: "Inventory Control", salary: 36500})
db.test.insert({emp_id: "006", emp_name: "Bill Washington", dept: "Inventory Control", salary: 38300 })
db.test.insert({emp_id: "007", emp_name: "Leslie Sanchez", dept: "Inventory Control", salary: 44200})

db.test.insert({emp_id: "008", emp_name: "", dept: "Accounts Payables", salary: 44200})
db.test.insert({emp_id: "009", emp_name: "", dept: "Accounts Payables", salary: 44200})


db.test.insert({emp_id: "010", emp_name: "Linda Le", dept: "Accounts Receivables", salary: 45200})
db.test.insert({emp_id: "011", emp_name: "Sanjay Gupta", dept: "Accounts Receivables", salary: 50100})
db.test.insert({emp_id: "012", emp_name: "Toshaki Soja", dept: "Accounts Receivables", salary: 48400})

db.test.insert({emp_id: "013", emp_name: "Chimchzu Choi", dept: "Testing", salary: 44800})
db.test.insert({emp_id: "014", emp_name: "Dana Bearnson", dept: "Testing", salary: 55600})
db.test.insert({emp_id: "015", emp_name: "Gladys Smith", dept: "Testing", salary: 47500})
```

We can show the employee names and salary for employees working in the "Testing department" with the following aggregation...

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $match: { "dept": "Testing" } },
    { $project: { _id: 0, emp_name: 1, salary: 1} }
])
```

**Results:**

```
{ "emp_name" : "Chimchzu Choi", "salary" : 44800 }
{ "emp_name" : "Dana Bearnson", "salary" : 55600 }
{ "emp_name" : "Gladys Smith", "salary" : 47500 }
```

... and we can find the minimum salary for each department with the following aggregation...

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$dept",
            minSalary: { $min: "$salary" }
        }
    }
])
```

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : "Testing", "minSalary" : 44800 }
{ "_id" : "Accounts Receivables", "minSalary" : 45200 }
{ "_id" : "Accounts Payables", "minSalary" : 44200 }
{ "_id" : "Sales", "minSalary" : 45000 }
{ "_id" : "Inventory Control", "minSalary" : 36500 }
```

... notice some people have the same (lowest) salary in the group, but since they are not part of the grouping the count of records is 1 per department.